# HOW ARE Node a and Node* s different?

Tags: c++, struct

```
struct Node
{
    int w;
    Node* w1;
};
int main(){
    Node a;
    Node *s;
}
```

In above code what is difference between a and *s. How are they different.Also why we use Node *s while creating a LinkList.
THANK YOU!!!

Comment: The type of `Node a;` is **Node**.  The type of `Node* s;` is **pointer** to a Node.  The `s` could point to a Node or possibly nullptr, or possibly Bad Things™ (dangling pointer, garbage pointer).

Answer (score 1):

Node a is an object. It allocates some space in memory.
Node *s1 - is pointer to object of type Node, but the object itself must be created with, for example, a new operator. Or we must explicitly take and address of the object with & operator. It is just a variable that holds an address. The size of this variable depends on platform (4 bytes on x86, 8 bytes on x86_64).

Each node of a Linked list stores a pointer to the next node. That is why we need a pointer here. Thus if you you have access to the node, you can travel to the next and to the end of the list.

Disclaimer: The given code is very basic and given for explanation only. This is not how you create linked list in real-life. Manually connecting nodes is not a great pattern. I would recommend you to learn more about basic language concepts like pointers, references, object lifetime.

```
// Node type definition
struct Node
{
   int w;
   Node* w1;
};

int main() {
    // Separate nodes
    Node n1;
    Node n2;
    Node n3;
    
    // Now this is a linked list
    n1.w1 = &n2;
    n2.w1 = &n3;
    n3.w1 = nullptr; // to mark the end
    
    // Get pointer to n2 from n1
    Node *n2_ptr = n1.w1;
    Node *n3_ptr = n2.w1;
    // Check if n3 is the last element
    if (n3_ptr->w1 == nullptr) {
        // this is the end of the list
    }
    
    // walk the list
    Node *node = &n1;
    while (node != nullptr) {
        node->w *= 2; // do smth with data
        node = node->w1; // go to the next node
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If someone does not know what pointers are, the using `n1.w1 = &n2;` as an explanation how to create a linked list ist a really bad idea. Because then the person most certainly does also know enough about storage duration and that doing this might lead to pointer pointing to deleted node and that you won’t really create a linked list like that.

Comment: Noted, thanks! Added a disclaimer and put the code into a function.